# Appending data to owl carousal using ajax ,jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, owl-carousel

Iam trying toad data in owl carousal using ajax.but its appending data one below the other.

HTML

```html
<div id="hd_estrutura">
<div class="bot_e">
<h1>Name</h1>
</div>
<div class="fa"></div>
<div class="boxouter">  
<div id="imgbox" class="owl-carousel owl-theme imgbox">
<div id="load"></div>//trying to load data from ajax here
</div></div>
</div> </div></div><!-- fim .miolo -->
```

Ajax

```js
$.ajax(
{
type:"post",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Ctrl/test",
data:{ 's_id':s_id},
success:function(data)
{ 
$("#load").append(data);
}
}
);
```

Data need to append in div with id load

```html
<div  class="item"><a href="" class="paraent-container" ><img src=""></a><ul><li ><p class="name">huj</p></li><li><p class="value">ghj</p> </li></ul><button id="testbutton" class="snip1479">Add to cart 1</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The alignement of items in the carousel is done by javascript. When loaded the carousel is empty, the plugin is not resizing anything. But when you add your content using an ajax query, you are not calling the plugin and asking it to align item.
You need to **call your plugin** just **after appending the data** and **not when loading your page**.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Ctrl/test",
    data:{ 's_id':s_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
        $("#load").append(data);
        $("#load").owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: not working.when I try to append data the owl carousal clone function is not working.I think thats why alighnment is changing.Is there any solution for that.@Oussama

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$.ajax(
{
type:"post",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Ctrl/test",
data:{ 's_id':s_id},
success:function(data)
{ 
 $('#load').html('<div id="imgbox" class="owl-carousel owl-theme imgbox"></div>');
$(".owl-carousel").append(data);
$("#imgbox").owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
0:{
items:1
},
600:{
items:3
},
1000:{
items:5
}
}
});
}
}
);
```

Note:Please ignore syntax errors.

Comment: Working perfect.